# javascript - Copy file from one directory to another

Tags: javascript

How could I use javascript to copy `C:\folderA\myfile.txt` to `C:\folderB\myfile.txt`? I also have to check to make sure that `myfile.txt` does not already exist in `folderB`. And finally I have to then rename the new file from `myfile.txt` to `myfile.bak`.

I know javascript can't really be used on a local file system, but if it could be, how would I write this code as simply as possible?

Comment: Is this server-side JavaScript, i.e. can you use node.js (and the fs module) or do you need to run this from a client browser?

Comment: You can use Nodejs to access your local file system

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with node.js.  I basically have to just write it in regular javascript and in a client browser.

Comment: @user2051533 client side you can't.

Comment: how about non-client side??

Comment: I'm looking for a code snippet to do this:

Comment: 1) copy myfile.txt from source directory to destination.
2) check to make sure file does not already exist.
3) rename the file from .txt to .bak

Answer (score 20):

in browser side you cannot access local system files.But in server side you could do it as follows.

```
//copyfile.js
const fs = require('fs');

// destination will be created or overwritten by default.
fs.copyFile('C:\folderA\myfile.txt', 'C:\folderB\myfile.txt', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('File was copied to destination');
});
```

nodejs has to be [installed](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) on your server and then run above script as follows

```
node copyfile.js
```

Comment: It is possible to access local system files in browsers that support the [File System Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_Access_API).